# Traveling from Colombia to Brazil - do I need yellow fever vaccination?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, brazil, south-america, colombia

So I’m in kind of a difficult situation. I just realised that I might need proof of having had the yellow fever vaccination to get into Brazil. I’m leaving to Brazil in 4 days and I am planning on getting the vaccination tomorrow in Colombia. However, it needs 10 days for the vaccination to work - do you think I’ll have trouble at check-in/Brazilian immigration? From what I understand, Brazil does not require proof of yellow fever vaccination on departure/arrival from Colombia but it’s unclear.

Thanks for the help/advice!

Answer (score 1):

In the past four and a half years, I've traveled into Brazil on a few dozen occasions. I've entered by plane, in Rio and Sao Paulo, and by land from several countries. Not once was proof of my yellow fever vaccination requested.

So, I'm pretty sure you'll be fine.

Comment: I agree. I just returned from a trip from Asúncion to the Iguassu Falls, crossing into Brasil at Foz. The immigration people didn't ask about vaccinations at all. They didn't ask about *anything,* but only stamped my passport.

Comment: Iguazu is notoriously easy :)